# Finding Probability $P(X^2 \leq X)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm looking to find the probability that $P(X^2 \leq X)$ with $X$ having a cfd which is a piecewise function

Comment: Observe that $X^2\le X$ is equivalent to $0\le X\le 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$X^2 \le X \iff X(X - 1) \le 0$$

giving $X^2 \le X \iff 0 \le X \le 1$. Should be straightforward to continue from there.